# Executing a Bat file on Azure remotely

Tags: azure, playframework, gitlab, command-line-interface

Currently I have a Play application that is being deployed to azure with FTP. After the deploy is successful I need to execute a bat file "run_app.bat" to start my play application on my azure website.

The build is running on Gitlab, and the file on Azure is located in the wwwroot directory.

Is there anyway I can add a command to my gitlab build that will execute this file? Im trying to automate the deployment process.

Note: Im really green with matters such as this, azure and devops

I tried finding a way to connect to Azure using the azure cli but I was unable to discover any commands that were suited to my needs. Read a bit about WebJobs but failed to understand how they work or how to set them.
Tried seeing if the Kudu console was accessible from a command line but got negative feedback on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run your batch file with Kudu Debug Console. Just execute `.bat` file in the CMD console.

[image]

And about deployment with custom scripts you could refer to this [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script) and [blog](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.XGOKgDMzaUk). And there is a [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments) in the wiki, it shows the detailed the steps to set the Customizing deployments.

If you still have other questions, please let me know.

Comment: But doesn't that defeat the whole purpose of automating tasks? I would like to Mae a deploy and not having to go to the kudu console and run the bat

Comment: @Joao Magalhães the pic is about how to run bat in Kudu, If you want to deploy with custom scripts you could refer to links in my answer.  https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script    https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments